# How to get rid of freaking adds?

Tags: malware, spyware

see these screen shots
[image]

in the above picture...those green texts (marked with red pen) when i hover mouse on them an add pops up.

this one is more annoying

[image]

anytime this add slides from the right corner of screen.

and i think that this one was not here...
[image]

and this is not only happening to this site but any other site where i surf.
maybe some (malware,spyware or addware) has infected my PC

how can i get rid of them ?

edit: this has been happening from couple of days

Comment: Check what extensions you have? chrome://extensions

Comment: @DanD. there are many..

Comment: Under the ads they say `Ads by BetterSurf`. Perhaps you have an extension with the same name.

Comment: nope...by the way that text has been changed to    Ads by Media Player

Comment: i clicked another text appearing beside it(it was not there before) it took me to some website and explained me about adds and there was an option of switching it off and it switched off (i am v. happy)

Comment: clean your web browser cookies.

Comment: @Nidzaaaa how to do that?

Comment: [SEE HERE](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en)

Comment: @Nidzaaaa will this process make my progress on online games disappear ?(I play online games)

Comment: Probably. 
Since you're playing online games (I asume that you're talking about those 'MiniClip' games or something like that) that's why you have got all those ads showing on your webpages.

Comment: so i'll be loosing all my progress ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try blocking these ads by DNS. If you are using Windows you can edit the `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. You should give e.g. 127.0.0.1 to the address for the ad servers.

Comment: what should i modify ?there (3) folders (2) .wdf files and (311) .sys files

Comment: modify the hosts file with notepad or any text editor post your email address and i will send the file

Comment: after looking carefully i got a file named gmreadme.txt now what should i do?